# sfdisk: create a partition from the right

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, bash, fdisk

I want to create partition 2 with a specified size, while partition 1 occupies the rest of the disk:

```
echo -en 'g\nw' | fdisk "$2" #create gpt table
echo -en ',1331200\n,,U' | sudo sfdisk "/dev/sda" -W always
```

The last command creates the left partition of 650MB and the right one occupying the rest of the disk, but as I have already specified, this is not what I need. To create the right partition of 650MB and the left one occupying the rest of the disk, I thought I'd do something like this:

```
echo -en ',-1331200\n,,U' | sudo sfdisk "/dev/sda" -W always
```

with the thought that the negative values started from the right, but instead the `-` sign is completely ignored and the command has the same effect as the one without the `-` sign.

How do I create a partition starting from the right using `sfdisk`?

Comment: What environment are you running this fragment in? Would text processing of `sfdisk --list` help? Consider using `expect` to automate your conversation with `sfdisk`. Read `man expect`

Comment: In what sense which environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see anything in the `sfdisk` documentation that suggests it supports a negative relative value.  Would it work to calculate the partition start position?

I'm going to demonstrate using a sparse loopback file simulating a 2GB disk

```
root@ubuntu:~# fallocate -l 2G filesystem.img
root@ubuntu:~# losetup -f filesystem.img
root@ubuntu:~# losetup -a | grep filesystem.img
/dev/loop6: [2049]:20 (/root/filesystem.img)
```

The start position of your 650MB partition can be found by subtracting 650MB from the end of the disk.  `$(blockdev --getsize64 /dev/loop6) / 1024` provides the size of the disk in KiB.  `650 * 1024` is 650MiB in KiB.  Put it together to find how many KiB to use for the first partition.

```
root@ubuntu:~# echo $(( $(blockdev --getsize64 /dev/loop6) / 1024 - (650 * 1024) ))
1431552
```

This value can be used directly when creating the partitions with `sfdisk`

```
root@ubuntu:~# sfdisk /dev/loop6 <<EOF
> label: gpt
> 1431552KiB,,,-
> ,,,-
> EOF
...
New situation:
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 77816CA7-8A39-974B-A78D-CFCB2A5D66EC

Device         Start     End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/loop6p1 2863104 4194270 1331167  650M Linux filesystem
/dev/loop6p2    2048 2863103 2861056  1.4G Linux filesystem
...
```

You could also calculate the value on the fly

```
root@ubuntu:~# wipefs -a /dev/loop6
...
root@ubuntu:~# sfdisk /dev/loop6 <<EOF
> label: gpt
> $(( $(blockdev --getsize64 /dev/loop6) / 1024 - (650 * 1024) ))KiB,,,-
> ,,,-
> EOF
...
New situation:
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 661C7E48-3342-3842-81BE-1AF4CB51BC6E

Device         Start     End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/loop6p1 2863104 4194270 1331167  650M Linux filesystem
/dev/loop6p2    2048 2863103 2861056  1.4G Linux filesystem
...
```

The previous examples created your 650MB partition first.  That can be a bit confusing since the partitions are not in the typical order.  You can create the "rest of the disk" partition first to avoid confusion.

```
root@ubuntu:~# wipefs -a /dev/loop6
...
root@ubuntu:~# sfdisk /dev/loop6 <<EOF
> label: gpt
> ,$(( $(blockdev --getsize64 /dev/loop6) / 1024 - (650 * 1024) ))KiB,,-
> ,,,-
> EOF
...
New situation:
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3EF08C46-AF4F-1F48-B8AF-A65D67C438B7

Device         Start     End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/loop6p1    2048 2865151 2863104  1.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/loop6p2 2865152 4194270 1329119  649M Linux filesystem
...
```

Comment: Thanks to you my problem has been solved.